# Synchronized Data Extension doesnt appear in Data Designer

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, contactbuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, data-synchronization

I just synchronized a new object in Marketing Cloud that cames from Salesforce through the native Connector, but the generated Synchronized Data Extension hasn't been added in the Data Designer.

As far as I know, it is added automatically. How can I know what is happening this? Is it related to the way the objects are related in between in Salesforce or to Marketing Cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing this issue with Salesforce Support, a relation between Invoice and Account had to be done:

> To create a relation between these two objects, you can create a
>   lookup field on custom object "Invoice" which will lookup to Account
>   object. Below are the steps you may perform

1. Click on Setup Click on Object Manager
2. Click on the custom object "Invoice"
3. Click on "Fields and Relationships"
4. Click New Select "Lookup Relationship".
5. Select "Account" object from the 'Related To' picklist
6. Enter a name for your new field Next and Save.

Once it is done, this relation will be available in Contact Builder in Marketing Cloud for Contacts and Leads.

Answer (score 2):

In order for it to appear in the data designer, it has to finish its synchronization and then complete the "contacts registration".

After the first time you sync an object, it will pull in all the data and once it completes, it will attempt to register with your contact model. This will create the data extension under the Synchronized Data Extension folder and link it to the contact model in a your Salesforce Sync Data Source attribute group under the Data Designer.

[image]

The synchronized data source would look similar to this image once it completes.  [image]

Comment: It seems like that but still not appear in Data Designer. The object was sync yesterday so it has no sense it still doesn't appear.

Comment: Does anything appear in data designer for Salesforce Sync DE's?  What object are you syncing?  This would have to relate back to User/Lead/Contact in some manner as the data designer is used to link these objects to Marketing Cloud Contact ID's/Subscriber Keys.

Comment: It is just linked with User. Is it enough? I think it should be linked also with Contact/Lead. It is a custom object.